# converting mixed dataframe with list to pure dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

what is the easiest way to extract information from a list embedded within a dataframe?

```
    a<-data.frame(cyl=c(4,6,8),k=c("A","B","C"))
    j<-by(data=mtcars,INDICES=mtcars$cyl,function(x) lm(mpg~disp,data=x))
    a$l<-j

    t(sapply(a$l,coef))->a$t
```

But this results in a matrix embedded within the dataframe and it needs some massaging in order to have it as two columns in a with their associated column names.

What I'd like is an easier method to extract this information and have it stored in dataframe `a` with the associated column names.

EDIT_ This is what I had in mind, but I just found the procedure somewhat cumbersome.

```
t(sapply(a$l,coef))->a$t
as.data.frame(a$t)->g
g$cyl<-as.numeric(rownames(g))
merge(x = a,y = g)->a2
a2[,-c(3,4)]->a3
```

Any simpler ways of doing this?

Now, to complicate matters- What If I´d like to get the residuals from `a$l` by cylinder.

```
sapply(a$l,function(x) x[['residuals']])->a$t
```

How can I generate a new dataframe in a long format with two columns: cyl and residual that later can be merged with the original dataframe a?

Comment: Maybe I miss your point, but would you like to have just the intercept and the slope in a? In that case, why do you run `a$l<-j`? Just skip that and do `t(sapply(j,coef))->a$t`

Comment: Doesn't `t(sapply(split(mtcars, mtcars$cyl), function(df) lm(mpg ~ disp, df)$coef))` get you to the same point?

Comment: The point here is not the regression. Rather, it is how to extract the information from a list embedded within a data frame. The mtcars regression is just an example of a list within a data frame

Comment: This is probably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24723122/r-how-to-expand-data-frame-column-matrices-into-data-frame-columns. The answer shows that the solution of an embedded matrix is `do.call(data.frame, df)`. Your example has a special "by" object that complicates the coercion. Check `str(a[,3])` to see the complicated mess that `by` creates.

Answer (score 0):

Well--see my previous edit for the first answer. This is for my second problem:

It does solve my problem, but I´m sure there must be a quicker and more intuitive way of solving this.

```
flat.list.df<-function(list,sublist){
  nm<-names(list)
  i<-do.call(rbind,lapply(nm,function(x){

    u<-list[[x]][[sublist]]

   g<-length(u)
   j<-rep(x,g)
   m<-data.frame(var=j,val=u)
   m
  })
  )
  return(i)
}

flat.list.df(a$l,"residuals")->w
w

merge(w,a,by.x="var",by.y="cyl")
```